# How to ssh into a remote machine by passing through multiple bridges machines, become another user and run a command as that user

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I need to save in a variable on my local machine a value that is returned from a script or command - let's take `bash /tmp/script1.sh` for the example - which lies on a remote machine - let's say **machine_C**, at path */tmp/script1.sh* and contains:

```
#! bin/bash

echo "Hello! I am speaking from remote machine: $(hostname -I)"
```

However, this machine can only be reached via ssh by passing through more than one bridge machine, in my case two - let's say **machine_P** and **machine_C**.

Furthermore, because of access lock, only a particular user - let's say **user_O** - present on **machine_B**, can access the next machines, so when my code reach **machine_B**, it needs to switch to **user_O**.

Note: I cannot ssh in **machine_B** directly as **user_O** because of access lock.
Also, I want add a timeout to my ssh command, so that if the access fails, the process does not remain struck forever.

So the procedure is

1. access **machine_B** as **user_B**,
2. from that machine, switch to **user_O** and access **machine_P** as **user_O**,
3. From that machine, access **machine_C** as **user O**,
4. in machine_C, run the commmand `bash /tmp/script1.sh`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer:

```
ssh_timeout=3

ip_string=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_B@$remote_machine_B_ip                         \
              "sudo -i -u user_O ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_P_ip  \
                  \"ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_C_ip               \
                      \"bash /tmp/script1.sh\"                                          \
                  \"                                                                              \
              "                                                                                   \
          )
```

### Explanation:

First, we need a variable where to store the value returned from **script1.sh**, so we start by:

```
info=...
```

then we need to run a command that will in the end run the script on **machine_C** to get that value:

```
info=$(...)
```

then we do the first ssh into **machine_B** as **user_O**, with timeout option (`-o ConnectTimeout=seconds`),
and the command that we want to be run by ssh must be put between delimiters; we choose double quotes (`"`):

```
info=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_B@$remote_machine_B_ip "...")
```

then **user_B** on **machine_B** must switch to **user_O** and then do a ssh into **machine_P** and run another command there.
That command must be enclosed in delimiters, and since we already used double quotes (`"`),
in order to avoid that the code reads this second couples of quotes as closure of the first ones,
we must escape them with `\`, so that they will be read as quotes only when the code run as **machine_P**:

```
info=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_B@$remote_machine_B_ip "sudo -i -u user_O ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_P_ip  \"...\" ")
```

let's put this command in a more understandable form by displaying it into multiple lines.
In order to prevent the code to stop reading the command as we break the line, we must escape the new line with `\`

```
info=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_B@$remote_machine_B_ip \
            "sudo -i -u user_O ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_P_ip  \"...\" "   \
        )
```

then **user_O** on **machine_P** must do a ssh into **machine_C** and run a command.
That command must be enclosed in delimiters, and again, since we already used double quotes (`"`),
in order to avoid that the code reads this third couples of quotes as closure of the first ones,
we must escape them.
 And again, let's put the command on multiple lines:

```
info=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_B@$remote_machine_B_ip                                  \
                  "sudo -i -u user_O ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_P_ip  \
                      \"ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_C_ip \"...\" \"                                                                              \
                  "                                                                                   \
              )
```

In the very end, we have to put the command we want to be run on **machine_C** in the `\"...\"` slot we prepared before.
The syntax of this command is exactly the same as the one we would use to write and run this command on our local machine, if the same script were at the indicated location.

```
# define ssh_timeout
ssh_timeout=3

info=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_B@$remote_machine_B_ip                         \
              "sudo -i -u user_O ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_P_ip  \
                  \"ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_C_ip               \
                      \"bash /tmp/script1.sh\"                                          \
                  \"                                                                              \
              "                                                                                   \
          )

echo "$info"
```

and the output is

> `I am speaking from remote machine: <remote_machine_C_ip>`